# how I can read the content of the dataset in pkl file and return 67 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'in python?

Tags: machine-learning, python, large-datasets, deep-learning

I have a dataset in pkl file, and I write the following code to unpkl the file and read the data

```
import pickle
f=open("data_cdg.pkl","rb")
a = pickle.load(f)
f.close()
print(a)
```

but I got in the output 67 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>' so how I can read the content of the dataset in python?

Answer (score 0):

There is a `read_pickle` function as part of `pandas` **0.22+**

```
import pandas as pd

object = pd.read_pickle("data_cdg.pkl")
```

Comment: I got the same result , i need to read the content of data set when i wrote your code i got this output so how I can read the content of data?67x67 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
 with 132 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>, 39773: <172x172 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
 with 342 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>, 1396: <17x17 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
 with 32 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>, 623: <125x125 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'